# iPad 2 Broken Screen!

Tags: ipad, backup, data-transfer

I dropped my iPad 2 and the LCD broke so I can't see what's happening. Is there a way I can see my iPad screen on my computer so I can make a backup of the files in specific apps. I know that you can mirror iOS 8 or higher devices using the lightning adapter but since this is the iPad 2, it's still using the 30 pin connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bummer to hear!

Fortunately, Apple does a great job in allowing you transfer data between devices.

I'm not certain on your meaning of "backup of the files in specific apps"; however, I have two suggestions that may be of help.

1. Plug your iPad into a *trusted* computer. This refers to a computer which has been used to sync your iPad in the past. From here you can [back up your device with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/KM205110?cid=acs::applesearch)
   .
2. [*PAID SOLUTION*] Third party software is available which will allow you to backup a bit more data than iTunes allows, which is especially useful if you do not plan to purchase another iOS device. I've used a software like [iSkySoft iTunes Recovery](http://www.iskysoft.com/iphone-data-recovery-mac/itunes-data-recovery-for-mac.html), which is expensive but does the job well. Search around, I'm sure there are cheapest (or free) solutions if you plan on going the third-party route.

Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but what I meant with "backup of files in specific apps"; For example the app Photo Vault. If you want to back up the files in Photo Vault, you have to be in the app to make a backup. But the problem is that the LCD is not working of my iPad 2. So I can't really see what I'm doing.

Comment: According to the developers website:

1) On your old phone, backup your phone to iTunes by plugging your phone into your computer and launching iTunes.
2) When you get a new phone, restore from the iTunes backup on your old phone.